# "I wear a tie at work" or "I wear ties at work"?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Do I have to use the word *tie* in the plural or singular form if want to say that generally I wear one tie at work? For example:

> I always wear a **tie**/**ties** at work.

Comment: As you only wear one at a time, singular would be usual.

Comment: What if I want ask someone if they like wearing a ties in general, do I "dovyou like wearing a tie or ties"?

Comment: I think either would be acceptable.